# Using an index in a loop to set unique attributes

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im using a loop to render a `<div>` with tabs in it for each item in a list:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.things)
{
    int counts = 1;

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- BOX -->
        <div class="box border red">
            <div class="box-title">
                <h4><i class="fa fa-columns"></i><span class="hidden-inline-mobile">@item.Name</span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="tabbable header-tabs">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class=""><a href="#box_tab2"  data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> <span class="hidden-inline-mobile">More</span></a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="#box_tab1" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> <span class="hidden-inline-mobile">Profile</span></a></li>

                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="box_tab1">
                            <p>Content #1</p>
                            <p>...</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="box_tab2">
                            <p>Content #2</p>
                            <p>...</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /BOX -->
    </div>
}
```

The problem here is  the harcoded values in for example:

```
<a href="#box_tab2>   that "opens"  the tab id="box_tab2".
```

Of course this does not work when there are several tabs with the same ids.
Can I maybe use an index in order to be able to assign unique values where needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right way using a counter/index, you have to use it to build your IDs, in your `nav-tabs`:

```
<li><a href='@String.Format("#box_tab1_{0}", count)'>
<li><a href='@String.Format("#box_tab2_{0}", count)'>
```

and in your `tab-content`:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id='@String.Format("box_tab1_{0}", count)'>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id='@String.Format("box_tab2_{0}", count++)'>
```

Note `count++` to increment counter after last usage in each loop iteration.